# Logical problems in SQL procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I'm writing a procedure that is supposed to do the following:

- Create a procedure that adds item (s) to an order.
- The number of what is in stock for the item must also be reduced by the same number.
- If no_of_items are more than what is in stock, the highest possible should be added so that stock is zero.
- The procedure must respond with a status of how many items have been added and warn or inform if the number was not as many as desired.
- If there are no items in stock, information must also be provided.
- Check must also be done so that the order ID and item ID are available.
- It should only be possible to add items to an order if it has shipping_status set to "open".

The procedure I have written looks as following:

```
    DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE add_item_to_order(order_id INT, item_id INT, no_of_items INT)
BEGIN
IF order_id IN (SELECT number FROM Orders WHERE Orders.status = "open")  THEN
IF item_id IN (SELECT number FROM Items WHERE Items.stock = 0) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE "45000" SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "item is not in stock";
    END IF;
    SET @stock = (SELECT Items.stock FROM Items WHERE Items.number = item_id);
 IF no_of_items <= @stock  THEN
 WHILE no_of_items > 0 DO
    INSERT INTO orders_items (o_id, i_id) VALUES (order_id, item_id);
    UPDATE Items SET Items.stock = (Items.stock - no_of_items) WHERE Items.number = item_id;
    SET no_of_items = no_of_items - 1;
    END WHILE;
    SELECT (no_of_items) AS "Item has been added. Amount of items: " ;
    END IF;
IF no_of_items > @stock THEN
 WHILE no_of_items > 0 DO
    INSERT INTO orders_items (o_id, i_id) VALUES (order_id, item_id - (item_id * no_of_items));
    UPDATE Items SET Items.stock = (Items.stock - no_of_items) WHERE Items.number = item_id;
    SET no_of_items = (no_of_items -1);
    END WHILE;
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE "45000" SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "Enough is not in stock. Biggest possible amount of items has been added" ;
    END IF;
ELSE SIGNAL SQLSTATE "45000" SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "Order must have status Open";
END IF;    
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The problem is that somethings are logically wrong because the output is not as expected. If I try to call it with:  CALL add_item_to_order(7, 5, 2), it should add two rows because no_of_items are 2, but it only adds one row. I need help with figuring out how I should write instead so it gives the correct output.

Also, if anyone has advice on how I can improve this query, I would very much appreciate it. I have written this procedure for a couple of days and can't figure out if its good written or bad.

Comment: When you create an `orders_items` for every 1 item on the order (so 2 lines, when 2 items of same `item_id` are sold). you should decrease stock with 1, and not with `no_of_items`.

Comment: Create a sample. Provide CREATE TABLE for all 3 tables, some initial data (3-5-7 rows per table), or the same as online fiddle. Then provide INSERTs which you should to perform, at least one query for each possible situation, and for each of them show desired final data state or SIGNAL message.